# Opening calendar in IE redirects to an url with ?ShowInGrid=False parameter and then an error is shown

Tags: calendar, browser-compatibility

When I open the calendar.aspx in IE7, the page loads fine and I can see the calendar but the page then gets automatically redirected to a calendar.aspx?ShowInGrid=False which then produces an error:

> The list is displayed in Standard view. It cannot be displayed in Datasheet view for one or more of the following reasons: A datasheet component compatible with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation is not installed, your browser does not support ActiveX controls, a component is not properly configured for 32-bit or 64-bit support, or support for ActiveX controls is disabled.

I cannot figure out why this happens and why is it only with IE.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Is this error happening on IE at your home or work site?  At some work sites, for security reasons, Administrators will disable ActiveX controls.  If you dont have ActiveX enabled, you cannot edit the calendar in DataSheet view.

Try to enable the ActiveX controls in IE following these steps:

```
1. Select Tools -> Internet Options
2. Select Security Tab
3. Select the zone in which your SharePoint portal is in.  
4.  Click the Custom Level button
5.  Scroll down and Enable
  -Run ActiveX Controls and Plugins
  -Script ActiveX Controls Marked Safe for Scripting
6.  Click Apply and restart IE.
```

Hope this helps.